# Formatting fileds using android views

Tags: android, formatting, textview

Is there any good simple way to format fields as I want.

I'd like to separate field value from field text. For example, I'd like to group number by 4, so when I set field's value to `123456789` it would show as `1 2345 6789`, but when I get value I'll get number without spaces (`123456789`).

I think, this is the way widgets works on other tools, i.e. .Net VS. I can set there some mapping, formats and so on, so what is shown depends on value and format/mapping.

In android this must be done for passwords fields. It has text as value, but it shows some dots (value is `mypassword` and field shows `**********`).

Comment: @AshaSoman For start I'd like to have field when I put number, get number and work on number inside app, but user see this number formatted - with spaces for example.

Comment: have you tried TransformationMethod ?

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks, unfortunately it needs formatted text to has same length as source text. But it was closest I get to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you just want to display the number in nice format, please use the APIs provided by PhoneNumberUtils.

```
static String    formatNumber(String source)
static void  formatNumber(Editable text, int defaultFormattingType)
```

You could set the formatted string to the text view for displaying nicely. But the saved content is still the raw content without any format.

Please refer to the SDK document at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html

Comment: For now I want to format accounting number (`1 000.00` instead of `1000`). I can format string that way. What I need is gui to show this. I don't want to set text: `1 000.00` and then parse it back to `1000`.

Comment: I am not aware that there is any existing facility will help you to do that. If I were you, I will write my own TextView and override the setText/getText method to achieve this goal.

Comment: Accept for answer in comment